# Show post to specific user, display assigned post on archive to specific user

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I added an ACF field User with (UserID) to custom post type.
So I want to display that posts only to a user I choose from the list.
Also I want to create an acrhvei page, that will show posts based on the user loggd in.
So if a user with xy username logs in, and there are posts that I've added to that user, he will see these posts, but if that user don't have any posts assigned from my side, it will be empty.

Also the post link should be restricted only to that user, so if someone shares a link to another user, who wasn't assigned, he wont be able to open it.

Note: I'm using several plugins, ElementorPRO, ACF, ProfileBuilder... if that means anything.

Can someone help me to achieve this?
Thank you

I've tried plugins with content resctriction, but it is only possible to restrict by user role, not by user.

EDIT: I've managed to create query based on the field I select (user) when adding a post, so now it only shows posts that match that field.
Using Advanced Queries + ACF.

The only thing now is, to restrict access if specific user is selected.
Thank you